# Cannot get Cypress test to work in React with Okta

Tags: reactjs, cypress, http-status-code-403, okta

I am trying to test my React (v16.10.2) application with Cypress (v4.5.0). Our application is using Okta for authentication (with the client @okta/okta-react 1.3.1).

I can use my app from the browser without any issues. The first time I login, I get the Okta login screen. I enter my user ID and password, and the react client calls the `authn` endpoint with my creds, and then calls the `authorization` endpoint to get the token. I am then taken to the first screen of our application.

When I try to login in my Cypress test, my user ID and password are entered into the login screen, the `authn` endpoint is called successfully, but the `authorization` endpoint returns a 403 error. Unfortunately, there is no other info about why I am getting the 403.

I have compared the `authorization` requests between the one that works in the browser, and the one that doesn't work from Cypress. The only real difference I see is that the working browser request has an `origin` header, whereas the failing one does not.

Question #1: Could the missing `origin` header be the cause of my problem?

In order to avoid a bunch of CORS and cross-site issues, I had to install a couple Chrome extensions (`ignore-x-frame-headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin-master`). I am implementing them in the following code in `cypress/plugins/index.js`:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        // The following code comes from https://medium.com/@you54f/configuring-cypress-to-work-with-iframes-cross-origin-sites-afff5efcf61f
        // We were getting cross-origin errors when trying to run the tests.
        if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
            const ignoreXFrameHeadersExtension = path.join(__dirname, '../extensions/ignore-x-frame-headers');
            launchOptions.args.push(`--load-extension=${ignoreXFrameHeadersExtension}`);
            const accessControlAllowOriginMasterExtension = path.join(__dirname, '../extensions/Access-Control-Allow-Origin-master');
            launchOptions.args.push(`--load-extension=${accessControlAllowOriginMasterExtension}`);
            launchOptions.args.push("--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,IsolateOrigins,site-per-process");
            launchOptions.args.push('--disable-site-isolation-trials');
            launchOptions.args.push('--reduce-security-for-testing');
            launchOptions.args.push('--out-of-blink-cors');
        }
        if (browser.name === 'electron') {
            launchOptions.preferences.webPreferences.webSecurity = false;
        }
        return launchOptions;
    });
```

I also added the following to `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Here is my cypress test:

```
describe('Order Lookup Test', () => {
    const UI_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    const ORDER_NUMBER: string = '10307906234';
    beforeEach(() => {
        Cypress.config('requestTimeout', 50000);
        cy.visit(UI_URL);
        cy.get('#okta-signin-username', {timeout: 10000}).type('xxxxxxxx');
        cy.get('#okta-signin-password', {timeout: 10000}).type('xxxxxxxx');
        cy.get('#okta-signin-submit', {timeout: 10000}).click();
    })
    it('should return an order', () => {
        cy.get('.number-input', {timeout: 10000}).type(ORDER_NUMBER);
        cy.get('.order-lookup-buttons-search-valid').should('be.visible').click();
    })
})
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? What other information should I be including in order to help narrow this down?